# Submit form as anonymous user

Tags: rest, jhipster

Case:
Anonymous user visits the website, fills in a form and wants to submit it.

As you can see it doesn't differ with the creaton of an entity as if I am logged in.

```
   // Enlist a volunteer
           $scope.enlist = function () {

           $scope.isSaving = true;
           myEntity.save($scope.volunteer, onSaveSuccess, onSaveError); <-- same method
      };
```

The thing is I cannot reach the Restfull Service because it is somehow binded to an authentication.

When submitting the form, I get the following:

> POST [XHR] http://localhost:3000/api/myentity [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 11ms]

Followed by an redirect to the sign in page.

Is there a way to reach the rest endpoint (i.e. save) as an anonymous user?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the SecurityConfiguration class and unprotect the URL for your entity

```
   .antMatchers("/api/myentity").permitAll()
```

Comment: Already tried that, but somehow Springboot keeps its settings.

Comment: Please note that the order of antMatchers is important